# NotReadablePropertyException Bean property is not readable or has an invalid getter method

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-form

Having error: `org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'organizations' of bean class [com.sprhib.model.Team]: Bean property 'organizations' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?`

There are tables: teams, organization. There is One-to-Many relationship.

**Team model**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="teams")
public class Team {

    private Organization organization;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "FK_Organization_id", nullable = false)
    public Organization getOrganization() {
        return organization;
    }

    public void setOrganization(Organization organization) {
        this.organization = organization;
    }
}
```

**Organization**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "organization")
public class Organization {
    private Set<Team> teams;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "organization")
    public Set<Team> getTeams() {
        return teams;
    }

    public void setTeams(Set<Team> teams) {
        this.teams = teams;
    }
}
```

**JSP**

```
<form:form method="POST" commandName="team" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/team/add.html">    
     <form:select path="organizations">
         <form:option value="${organization}">
             <c:out value="${organization.name}"/>
         </form:option>
     </form:select>
</form:form>
```

How to make spring get all organizations to JSP?

**UPDATE:**

I pass a list of *all organizations* and new Team object to jsp using controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/team")
public class TeamController {

    @Autowired
    private TeamService teamService;

    @Autowired
    private OrganizationService organizationService;

    @RequestMapping(value="/add", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView addTeamPage() {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("teams/add-team-form");
        modelAndView.addObject("team", new Team());
        modelAndView.addObject("organizations", organizationService.getOrganizations());

        return modelAndView;
    }
```

UPDATE2:

Does `commandName="team"` restricts usage of more than 1 model attributes, in this case there are two: `organizations` and `team`? How to make it work?

> Custom attribute name: commandName Description: Name of the model
>   attribute under which the form object is exposed. Defaults to
>   'command'. Required: false Can have runtime value: true

Comment: When you say _all organizations_, what do you mean?

Comment: it seems you are trying to fetch organisations property from the Team class; but the Team class only has (a single) organisation. The organisations property does not exists (and that's what the exception message is telling you).

Comment: Why do you need a `form` for the `Team` bean?

Comment: I use the form to add new `Team` object and store it. I had to specify something for `commandName` property...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<form:option>` is used to append a single option to a select list. You can add all of elements in a collection using `<form:options>`"

```
<form:select path="organization">
    <form:options items="${organizations}" />
</form:select>
```

you can also use both, like for adding a default unselected option:

```
<form:select path="organization">
    <form:option value="" label="- Select -"/>
    <form:options items="${organizations}" />
</form:select>
```

The value which will be selected, will end in the Team bean passed thru the form; the `path` attribute is used for determining which property will be set in Team, in this case it is `organisation` (not organisations)

Comment: Thanks, now it works! But there one more thing - I need to display the name of each organization in drop-down. At the moment it shows objects. I tried `itemLabel` as described here but it is not working: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/spring-form.tld.html#spring-form.tld.options

Comment: like in `<form:options items="${organizations}" itemLabel='name' />` ? it should work